# Port forward to different port number

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, port-forwarding

I have a router that sets up rules like so:

```
TCP Any -> 5800
Any -> 5900
UDP Any -> 5800
Any -> 5900
Computer: ip-address
```

This would allow someone 'outside' to connect to my router's port 5800 and 5900 and forward that to the same port on my computer.

My issue is that I want the 'outside' port to be different without changing the port on my computer.

Comment: i'm pretty sure this has been asked before, but my search-fu is failing at the moment.

Comment: I couldn't find one either...weird.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate using a Linux box as a router.  iptables has a REDIRECT target that does just what you are saying, and I use it myself.  On my home LAN I like to keep things on standard ports, but don't necessarily want them externally accessible through the same ports.  Or sometimes I've chosen a nonstandard port for a service, but want one specific IP to access it through the standard port due to their restrictive policies.

For example, I have my SSH port changed from the default one, but have added a rule in my firewall to redirect port 22 (the standard port ) to this port for a specific IP (which is my school, which blocks my chosen nonstandard port)

Comment: I figured it out you set each of them to "Any -> " followed by the "external" port and use another setting to change the port used 'internally'.

This requires the above rule to become two to be functional.

Answer (score 0):

On my D-Link router, there is an option to set the "public" (outside) and "private" (inside) ports. What router are you using?

Simulator:
http://support.dlink.com/Emulators/wbr2310/adv_virtual.htm